# How to check if I have bad links in my Wordpress site?

Tags: google, wordpress, web-development, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I have Wordpress site and recently receive bad from AdSense for invalid activity. Honestly I don't know why, but one of the things that may be is hidden link in my theme. The theme is not activated(nulled). I know this is wrong but I will activate the theme as soon as I can.

Can you tell me how to find if I have something wrong in theme ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First suggestion: pause all Google ads before your account gets locked down because Google is not known for reopen any closed AdSense accounts.

Second I would suggest checking your theme with the [Theme Authenticity Checker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tac/). It scans all theme files for potential malicious code.

Third: Try to find out if you receive bad traffic like Josip already mentioned (bots etc).

Fourth: How do you integrate the ads on your site? It it a custom widget or something offered by the theme or another plugin? If yes, try to hard-code the ads directly into the theme with the code you get from AdSense.

Comment: Thank you gor the answer. I can not stop ads because I don't have access to my AdSense account. So many people told me that if I fix the problem They can reactivate my account. Is that true ?

Comment: I think the possibility to reopen the account depends on what you exactly received from Google. Did they wrote about how to recover the account?

Comment: No.They do not even tell me the specific reason for disabeling my account.

Comment: Try to contact them. I bet it's some automated system mail and not even a human checked your account.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid click activity consists of any clicks or impressions that may artificially inflate an advertiser's costs or a publisher's earnings, and for which we decide not to charge the advertiser. This includes, but is not limited to, clicks or impressions generated by a publisher clicking on his own ads, a publisher encouraging clicks on his ads, automated clicking tools or traffic sources, robots, or other deceptive software.

Chances of getting back into the Adsense program are very very slim. 
You can read more at the Help Center:
https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=57153

Do you know the reason why you got banned ? It could  be most likely invalid clicks, you could file an appeal:
http://www.google.com/support/adsense/bin/request.py?contact=appeal_form

Once again chances of getting his account back are probably next to nothing. It's very important that Adsense Publishers take a pro-active stance and ensure that all terms and program policies are in full compliance.

Comment: Thank youbfor your answer.  What can I do to remove the ban when I don't know the reason ?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: I know this info. I send appeal 2 times but the sesilt was negative. If there are clicks from me, they not more than 3-4 and they are by mistake. If there are impressions from me they are to manage the content.  What can Before next appeal to make things right?